# Expanding just the Grid and not it's content using a storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard, blend

I'm trying to expand a grid using a storyboard, when you click on a button or a picture the grid should then expand, but the problem is that the content inside the grid like the second button I pasted inside the grid is also expanding. Is there someway I can expand the grid without expanding it's content inside. I had this problem with a stack panel, Text box, buttons, frames etc. O and I'm working with a WPf Application and it's XAML

A simple Xaml code:

```
  <Window x:Class="Try.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="3.028"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="106.5"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
  <Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="grid" Margin="75,35,337,107" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.544"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
    <Button Content="MyButton" Height="50" Width="50"  />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Can you expand on the behaviour of MyButton? You've set an explicit height on it, which should prevent it from growing taller or shorter, but you haven't set a fixed width. When the Grid grows or shrinks horizontally the Button will scale with it unless it has its own Width value set.

Comment: I just updated it again, is it something like that? (Sorry for wasting your time like this, and thanks for the help)

Comment: That *should* prevent the Button from changing size. Can you test it and confirm if it's working or not?

Comment: No it's still re-sizing

Comment: That'll teach me to post answers with a hangover. The problem is that you're applying Transforms to the Grid and everything in it, including the Button. There is, as far as I'm aware, no way to exclude child elements from the Transform. Couple of moderately kludgey options: 1) apply a second Transform just to the Button which downscales it by the inverse of your scaling factor (1/3.028 in this case), or 2) use a second Grid to hold the elements that shouldn't be scaled, and draw this on top of the Transformed Grid.

Comment: So I tried your second option and so far it's the closest answer to my question, thank you so much for your help. O and I hope your hangover passes quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the child elements inside your Grid explicit Heights and Widths.

```
<Grid>
    <Button Width="50" Height="50" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I think I tried that and still the same, I updated my Question and added the xaml code to show you more or less my problem.